# openshift oc need libcrypto.so.10

Tags: debian, openshift

When I use OpenShift CLI OC in Debian, it is showing a error message

> libcrypto.so.10: cannot open shared object file

I try to run

```
ln -s libcrypto.so.1.0.0 libcrypto.so.10
```

but another error message was shown

> 'OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC' not found
>   'libcrypto.so.10' not found.

Comment: libcrypt.so and libcrypto.so are two different libraries. You should never link files as you did (you can get worse errors, and unbootable system) Libcrypt is part of standard C library.

Comment: thank , i  changed the mistake,but oc already couldn't work. I found the method of making a symbol link from this site, and some one said it work in some software which also lost libcrypto.so.10. But it couldn't work on oc. I also download openssl on the official site and compile it , but no use.

Comment: Yes, I saw also that on this site. It seems that openssl is named also libcrypto [possibly on some version, to better handle different version/protocols] in fedora (so the symlink). So you may need to do the symlink, but with the correct version of openssl

Answer (score 5):

Thanks. I download oc from openshift help center before, and the right way is download from https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases for the new version.
Changing lib file is no need and stupid. I try many ways to revise oc lib, fix one error another is coming. Using new cli version is more clever.